# Angularjs checkbox in ng-repeat does not have a value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change, angularjs-ng-checked

I have the following problem: I have a parent checkbox and other children. If I use the ng-model parent, in the ng-check they are checked, until there it works ok.
When wanting to know if the ng-change attribute has changed, I do not get results until I click on the child checkbox.

**View**

```
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion" watch>
    <li ng-repeat="fleet in fleets">
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">send</i>
            <input type="checkbox" 
                   class="filled-in" 
                   id="{{fleet.nameFleet}}" 
                   ng-model="fleetObject[fleet.nameFleet]" />
            <label for="{{fleet.nameFleet}}">{{fleet.nameFleet}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <p ng-repeat="item in fleet.vehicles | filter:search">
                <input type="checkbox" 
                       class="filled-in" 
                       id="{{item.nameVehicle}}" 
                       ng-checked="fleetObject[fleet.nameFleet]" 
                       ng-model="vehicleObject[item.nameVehicle]" 
                       ng-change="viewVehicle()"/>
                <label for="{{item.nameVehicle}}">{{item.nameVehicle}}</label>
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
{{fleetObject | json}}
<br>
{{vehicleObject | json}}
```

controller

```
myApp.controller('fleets', function ($scope, $http, sharedProperties) {
var idFleet = sharedProperties.getProperty();
$scope.fleetObject = {};
$scope.vehicleObject = {};
//
$http.get(myUrl + 'AppVehicle/' + idFleet).then(function (response) {
    if (response.data.length != 0) {
        $scope.fleets = response.data;
        Materialize.toast('Flotas obtenidas', 2000);
    }
    else {
        Materialize.toast('No se encontraron Flotas', 2000);
    }
})
//
$scope.viewVehicle = function(){
    console.log('obj');
}});
```

please, could you help me with just checking the parent checkbox get the names of the children.
Already very grateful

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please clarify.

Comment: sorry if I explained wrong.
When you click on the parent checkbox, the children are checked, but the ng-change trigger does not trigger until you click on one of the children, there is a way to automatically trigger the children without having to click on them ?

Comment: No. Put a ng-change on the parent checkbox. Why is this ng-change useful? Why do you need to know when it changes? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying when selecting a parent checkbox, a function is triggered in all the children, I do not know if it's possible or I'm wrong along the way

Comment: I understand that, but why? Pure curiosity, or do you actually want to achieve something? If so, why? I'm asking because there might be a much better way to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: simply by selecting a fleet, you mark all the vehicles and show them to me on a map

Comment: Then surely you have a map directive, taking some array of vehicles as input, using an isolate scope binding. And the model of your form should be that input. The directive can watch the array of vehicles to know when it changes. And you don't need any ng-change. Just binding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157718/discussion-between-gabriel-sule-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: If you want to know if value of something has changed or not, use $watch for that variable.